# How can I find out what version of an application will be in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, package-management

Specifically, will LibreOffice version 3.5 be included in Pangolin (12.04)?

but more generally - I don't know how to determine what software packages are present in various Ubuntu releases.

Is that information available somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

Version 3.5.2.

You can see package versions on launchpad - for example, here: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice

On the command line:

```
rmadison -u ubuntu -s precise [packagename]
```

for example

```
 rmadison -u ubuntu -s precise libreoffice
```

will output

```
libreoffice | 1:3.5.2-2ubuntu1 |       precise | source, amd64, armel, armhf, i386, powerpc
```

Or from a precise install - look at the applications *Help - About*

for example:

[image: LibreOffice about dialog]

Comment: You can also get an early overview at: https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-p-libreoffice-packaging -- or for the next release https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-q-libreoffice-packaging

Answer (score 0):

It will be LibreOffice 3.5.1

More information like this https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/TechnicalOverview/Beta2#New_Applications_and_Defaults