# Will Gimp 2.8 ship with Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, gimp

In the Software Centre, Gimp 2.6 is still the available stable release. I've heard talk about Gimp 2.8 being almost ready (and Gimp 2.7 being unstable).

Will Ubuntu 12.04 ship with Gimp 2.8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GIMP won't be installed default on 12.04 because Canonical wants the ubuntu image to fit on a cd. And the software repositories will contain GIMP 2.6 because GIMP 2.8 isn't stable yet.

You can install GIMP [via the instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134035/how-do-i-get-gimp-2-8)

[List of software which will be installed by default in 12.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ubuntu-desktop)

---

Linked Question:

1. [How can I find out what version of an application will be in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124474/how-can-i-find-out-what-version-of-an-application-will-be-in-12-04)